# Espresso test is passed only first time. Then is failed constantly because of NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android-espresso

I work in Android Studio. I'm currently working on automation tests creation using Espresso 2.1:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
```

I have following xml layout for MainActivity class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="theMainMapViewFirst">
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout" android:background="@color/toolbar_bg">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPanMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onPanClick"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3pt"
        android:src="@drawable/map_pan"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectableLayers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3pt"
        android:src="@drawable/layer_basemap_analyze32"
        android:onClick="onSelectableLayersClick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@null" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do is to verify the second ImageButton from xml above is displayed. My code is:

```
@SmallTest
public void testSelectableLayersIsOpen()
{
    onView((withId(R.id.btnSelectableLayers))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

The code has worked only one time. And the test was successfully passed only once. After I tried to run the test second time (and a lot of more times) I receive the same error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: <package_name>:id/btnSelectableLayers
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=658, height=802, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=21.0, y=21.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->LinearLayout{id=16908990, res-name=parentPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+---->LinearLayout{id=16908991, res-name=topPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->LinearLayout{id=16908992, res-name=title_template, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>ImageView{id=16908294, res-name=icon, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+------>DialogTitle{id=16908993, res-name=alertTitle, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->FrameLayout{id=16908998, res-name=contentPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ScrollView{id=16908999, res-name=scrollView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->TextView{id=16908299, res-name=message, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->Space{id=16909004, res-name=textSpacerNoButtons, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->FrameLayout{id=16909000, res-name=customPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->FrameLayout{id=16908331, res-name=custom, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->ImageView{id=2131361875, res-name=imageView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=760, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->LinearLayout{id=16908995, res-name=buttonPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+----->Button{id=16908315, res-name=button3, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----->Space{id=-1, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+----->Button{id=16908314, res-name=button2, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----->Button{id=16908313, res-name=button1, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909171, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
```

I have no idea why it's happening. 
Also, if I'm adding a new line to the code - the test will passed again, and only one time again.
In my case I've added next line to the xml above:

```
android:contentDescription="theMainMapViewFirst">
```

and my test has passed green. But only one time. It was failed again on just next run.

Could you guys please help me with such kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that you have a dialog displayed on top of the activity when espresso is trying to find a view.

Take a look at the View Hierarchy dump that is outputted in the espresso exception to figure out what dialog it is and why it's showing up.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. You were right. It was AlertDialog which caused the problem. We've redesigned the dialog by making a separate activity. Now my tests work as expected. Thank you once again.