# Espresso test is passed only first time. Then is failed constantly

Tags: android, android-espresso

Espresso giving NoMatchingViewException

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805530/espresso-test-is-passed-only-first-time-then-is-failed-constantly-because-of-no) but my case seems a bit weird because i don't have anything visible above my activity as per my view hierarchy.

I'm performing a click on item in recycler view like this which opens a new activity with a view pager and then I check if my view pager is visible.

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(6, click()));
```

Only the first time it works and I can actually see the test opening view pager. Another weird thing is I tested this both on real device and emulator. They both are giving me different result the test on multiple runs sometimes passes completely in emulator whereas on real device it just passes the first time only.

```
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1776, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909227, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=72.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131492949, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131492950, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->CoordinatorLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppBarLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->Toolbar{id=2131492969, res-name=toolbar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->TextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=269, height=81, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=43.0, text=500px Api, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=120, height=168, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=960.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--------->OverflowMenuButton{id=-1, desc=More options, visibility=VISIBLE, width=120, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=12.0}
|
+------>FrameLayout{id=2131492970, res-name=contentFrame, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=168.0, child-count=1}
|
+------->FrameLayout{id=2131492971, res-name=main_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->RecyclerView{id=2131492990, res-name=main_grid, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=7}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=12.0, y=-132.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=546.0, y=-132.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=12.0, y=480.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=546.0, y=480.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=12.0, y=1092.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=12.0, y=1704.0}
|
+--------->AppCompatImageView{id=2131492982, res-name=photo_thumb, visibility=VISIBLE, width=522, height=600, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=546.0, y=1704.0}
|
+-------->ProgressBar{id=16908301, res-name=progress, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=144, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=468.0, y=780.0}
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1776.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=72, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.test.ScreenTest.testFullPhotoInteraction(ScreenTest.java:91)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:257)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

Any Help would be appreciate.. :)

Comment: you might have already figured out the problem by now. In case you haven't, it would be great if you could add more source code to your question for us to analyze to the problem.

Comment: Hi @Droidwala Here is the [link](https://github.com/kdani41/Sample500px/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/d500px/fivehundredpx/PhotoGridScreenTest.java#L80) if you want to see the exact code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Espresso test is passed only first time. Then is failed constantly because of NoMatchingViewException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805530/espresso-test-is-passed-only-first-time-then-is-failed-constantly-because-of-no)